# Can't get results from mySQL query to display in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am very new to PHP and can't seem to use mySQL data at all from PHP. The SQL query I wrote works fine in phpMyAdmin when I run it in the SQL editor, but the most I am able to get from the code is the following from var_dump. Nothing else displays anything at all.

```
resource(3) of type (mysql result)
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!!

```
<?php


    ini_set(‘display_errors’,1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");
    if (!$con) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("sharetrader", $con);

    $sharelist = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT tblStocks.stockSymbol, tblShareData.lookupDate FROM tblStocks LEFT JOIN tblShareData ON tblShareData.tickerCode = tblStocks.stockSymbol ORDER BY tblShareData.lookupDate ASC LIMIT 0 , 30");

    if (!$sharelist) {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    var_dump($sharelist);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sharelist)) {
      echo $row['tblStocks.stockSymbol'];
      }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

> I am very new to PHP

But you're making great progress - just missing some of the finer points.

try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sharelist)) {
  var_dump($row);
}
```

...and it should be obvious what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.. after changing the code as per your suggestion, I now get the following:

array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "0B67.L" ["stockSymbol"]=> string(6) "0B67.L" [1]=> NULL ["lookupDate"]=> NULL }  Etc, etc for each row.

but I am still not seeing my desired result from:

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sharelist)) {
  echo $row['tblStocks.stockSymbol'];
  }

Which is still outputting nothing at all. I can assume from this that the query is correct, but that I have messed up somehow on the syntax of the php being used to display the results.

Comment: The output of var_dump tells you the names of the elements in the array. It's `stockSymbol` instead of `tblStocks.stockSymbol`

Comment: No dice. Still returning absolutely nothing.

Comment: Code now looks as follows:

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sharelist)) {  
  echo $row['stockSymbol'];  
  }

Comment: Well.. I still have no idea what is wrong, but I rewrote while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sharelist)) {
 echo $row['stockSymbol'];
}
and now it works perfectly. Thank you all for your help :)